# WordPress insert Google Tag Manager code in head of specifc page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

Having a problem trying to insert Google Tag Manager events into the head of just one page of my site.

I have this code within my functions.php:

```
function dcl_hook_javascript() {
    if (is_page ('5722')) { 
    ?>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: 123456789 -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-123456789"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'AW-123456789');
    </script>
    <!-- Event snippet for Free Trial Request Form Submitted conversion page -->
    <script>
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-123456789/abcABCDdefEBEOCfx9AC'});
    </script>
        <?php
      }
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'dcl_hook_javascript');
```

and it's just not showing up on the page. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you confirmed the id is correct and your not in a cache?

Comment: Yes to both.

Wouldn't have posted here otherwise.

Comment: Generally when checking a page ID, it should be an `int`, not a `string`:  `is_page(5722)`. It should still work though (unless you have a page with the title or slug "5722"). is the [`wp_head()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) function being called on the page template that's loaded?

Comment: Yes, wp_head is definitely being called. Maybe I should try the permalink slug instead although there is no page called '5722'.

Comment: Turns out switching to permalink slugs instead of ID's did the trick.